# Google Cloud Compute Engine is Not Working

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I use google cloud platform to host my wordpress website. but sometimes the instance that runs my website will stop working and my website will go down. I use "f1-micro, 1 vCPU, 0.6 GB Memory".

How do I fix that?

And how do I make a backup so I don't lost all of the website?

Comment: "Will stop working and website will go down" - Can you elaborate this? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

More often that not, issue could be related to resource starvation. f1-micro machine type might not be enough. My suggestion would be to increase machine type for a few days to test. Once you have isolated the issue then you can move to the next steps such as internal logs investigation.

For backup purposes, please review [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots). Keep in mind if you want to keep an external IP address you need to reserve it so that you do not lose it.